# From LuaLaTeX unicode-math to ConTeXt typescript

Tags: fonts, context, unicode-math

In `LuaLaTeX` I have this code (Please correct me if I have written something inappropriate.)

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setmainfont[Path=./minion/,
   %Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont=*-Regular.otf,
    BoldFont=*-Bold.otf,
    %ItalicFont=EBGaramond-MediumItalic.ttf,
    ItalicFont=*-It.otf,
    %RawFeature=+cswh,
    ItalicFeatures={Scale=MatchUppercase},{Scale=MatchLowercase},%{Style=Swash},
    %BoldItalicFont=EBGaramond-BoldItalic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldIt.otf
    ]{MinionPro}

\newfontface\Swash{MinionPro-It}[
    Path=./minion/,
    Extension = .otf,
    Contextuals=Swash]
    \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsw}{\Swash}
    % \addfontfeature{ItalicFeatures={Style=Swash},{Scale=MatchUppercase},{Scale=MatchLowercase}},

%\newfontface\Cha[
%    Path=./minion/,
%    Extension = .ttf,
%    %UprightFont=*-Regular,
%    %AutoFakeSlant=0.15,
%    %AutoFakeBold=1.2,
%    ]{Chatelaine-Regular}
%\newfontface\MPI[
%    Path=./minion/,
%    Extension = .otf,
%   ]{MinionPro-It}

\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[Scale=1.09]
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[
     range=up/{num},
     Scale=1]

\setmathfontface\Neo[
     Path=./minion/,
     Extension = .otf,
     UprightFont=*,
     AutoFakeSlant=0.15,
     AutoFakeBold=1.2,
     Scale=1.09
     ]{NeoEuler}
\newcommand{\me}{\ensuremath{\Neo e}}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
   range=bb,
   Scale=MatchUppercase,
   Scale=1.09
   ]

\unimathsetup{math-style=upright}
\setmathfont[
    range=up/{greek,Greek}, script-features={},% sscript-features{},
    Path=minion/,
    Extension=.otf,
    UprightFont=*,
    AutoFakeSlant=0.15,
    AutoFakeBold=1.2,
    Scale=0.91
    ]{NeoEuler}

\renewcommand{\int}{\ensuremath{\char"222B}}
\setmathfont[range="222B,
      Scale=1.09
      ]{Erewhon Math}
```

to get `MinionPro` like main font, `Garamond-math` like math font with greeks letters from `NeoEuler`, blackboard math letters from `STIX2`, integral symbol from `Erewhon Math` font and a command for exponential `e` symbol due `NeoEuler`:

I was going through the documentation and some posts here to achieve the same in `ConTeXt`. Initially i wrote

```
\definefontfamily[mainface][mm][Garamond-Math]
\definefontfamily[mainface][rm][MinionPro]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,11pt]
```

and it works (with the `otf's` installed) but italics and bold letters are not returned either despite using `{\it }` and `{\bf }`. I don't have the greek letters nor the symbols of the other fonts either. With the `otf` files in folder I tried the following as a first step to get the symbols from the other fonts

```
\startenvironment mainface
    %0x80-0x97=GREEK
    \definefontfallback[Neo-fallback][file:NeoEuler.otf][0x80-x097][force=yes]
    %0x98-0xAF=greek
    \definefontfallback[Neo-fallback][file:NeoEuler.otf][0x98-0xAF][force=yes]
    \starttypescript [serif] [mainface]
        \definefontsynonym [Serif] [file:MinionPro-Regular.otf]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifCaps] [Serif] [features=smallcaps]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [file:MinionPro-Italic.otf]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifSwash] [SerifItalic] [features=swash]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [file:MinionPro-Bold.otf]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic] [file:MinionPro-BoldItalic.otf]
    \stoptypescript
    \starttypescript [math] [mainface]
        \definefontsynonym [mathgreek] [file:Garamond-Math.otf] [fallbacks=Neo-fallback]
    \stoptypescript
    \definetypeface [mainface] [rm] [serif] [mainface] [default] [features=default]
    \definetypeface [mainface] [mm] [math] [mainface] [default] [features=default]
\stopenvironment
\usetypescript[mainface][default]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,rm,mm,11pt]
```

but the pdf cannot be generated. When I try to open the pdf file I only get the message: `the pdf file is damaged`. Installing the fonts, if I do `[Neo Euler]` instead of `[file:NeoEuler.otf]` and something similar for `MinionPro` and `Garamond-Math`:

```
\startenvironment mainface
    %0x80-0x97=GREEK
    \definefontfallback[Neo-fallback][Neo Euler][0x80-x097][force=yes]
    %0x98-0xAF=greek
    \definefontfallback[Neo-fallback][Neo Euler][0x98-0xAF][force=yes]
    \starttypescript [serif] [mainface]
        \definefontsynonym [Serif] [MinionPro-Regular]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifCaps] [Serif] [features=smallcaps]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [MinionPro-Italic]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifSwash] [SerifItalic] [features=swash]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [MinionPro-Bold]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic] [MinionPro-BoldItalic]
    \stoptypescript
    \starttypescript [math] [mainface]
        \definefontsynonym [mathgreek] [Garamond-Math] [fallbacks=Neo-fallback]
    \stoptypescript
    \definetypeface [mainface] [rm] [serif] [mainface] [default] [features=default]
\usetypescript[mainface][default]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,rm,mm,11pt]
```

it is possible to generate the pdf file but the math fonts are not applied. The pdf file appears with `MinionPro` and `latinmodern-math` (`{\it }` and `{\bf }`no works).

It is clear that I am not considering something to get the results of the code for LuaLaTeX above, in ConTeXt. How can I achieve it?

Comment: "Please correct me if I have written something inappropriate." You set `Scale=MatchLowercase,Scale=MatchUppercase` -- aren't these options mutually exclusive?

Comment: There is always something new being learned :')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is too much code that I do not understand or that looks a bit odd, but let me show you a small (horrible) example where I use XCharter (I do not have Minion) as text, Garamond Math as math, and alter some alphabets/glyphs. This is likely not a complete answer, but it might get you going.

The file `foo-math.lfg` looks like this:

```
return {
    name = "foo-math",
    comment = "Goodies that complement foo.",
    author = "juanuni",
    mathematics = {
        tweaks = {
            aftercopying = {
              {
                tweak   = "replacealphabets",
                list    = {
                    {
                        source   = "uppercasescript",
                        target   = "uppercasecalligraphic",
                        filename = "latinmodern-math.otf",
                        rscale   = 1,
                    },
                    {
                        source   = "lowercasegreeknormal",
                        target   = "lowercasegreekitalic",
                        filename = "euler-math.otf",
                        rscale   = 1,
                    },
                    {
                        source   = { first = 0x222B }, -- integral
                        filename = "stixtwomath-regular.ttf",
                    },
                },
              }
            },
        },
    },
}
```

If you look in the ConTeXt distribution you will find some `.lfg` files, usually there is only one font that is used, and that one is tweaked. Above you only see one tweak, the `replacealphabets` one.

The small example file looks like this:

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [XCharter]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [Garamond Math]

\definefontfeature[default][default][goodies=foo-math.lfg]

\setupbodyfont[mainface,11pt]

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=3pt]

Text

\im{ a+b+c }

\im{\mathcal{ABC}}

\im{\alpha\beta\gamma}
 
\im{\int}

\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

Not so much to be said about it. The output looks like this:

[image: tweaked]

Looking carefully, we notice that we have Latin Modern for calligraphic, Euler-Math for greek, and a Stix Two Math integral sign.

This can be compared with the output if the `\definefontfeature` line is commented:

[image: only Garamond in math]

Comment: Looks very simple. I have an issue with subscripts of integral symbol. The subscripts appear horizontally aligned with superscripts. Is  a configuration in `lfg` file neccesary or do I just redefine the `\int` command with `struts`?

Comment: You can look for `moveintegrals` in the other goodie files. You can probably apply it _after_ you have changed the integral sign, but now I would say that you are really on your own. Mixing fonts like this is asking for problems (and looks bad to me).